# Katalon - How to access a element in a Table?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

Currently, I’m automating Xamarin iOS app using Katalon. I want to tap any element in a table. I’ve tried with  Select List Item By Index” but it fails to identify the element in a table. 
Do you know how to access the element in a table using Katalon?

Comment: Pls share the relevant code of your script

Comment: Share the HTML, at least for the table. And what does it mean "tap any element"?